# how do I reverse an unwanted upgrade to new software version?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade

I installed a version of simulation software Gromacs - version 2019.4 to make this compatible with an external computer. Around two weeks later I checked the version (gmx --version) and it was now version 2020.1 (2020.1-Ubuntu-2020.1-1). I wasn't notified or asked whether i wanted to upgrade the version - it just happened! it's useless now since the set up files prepared on my computer don't run on the external computer due to version incompatibility. Can I reverse this? Do I need to reinstall the previous version again? if I do this how do i stop this happening again??

---

The output of `apt-cache policy gromacs` is:

```
gromacs: 
  Installed: 2020.1-1 
  Candidate: 2020.1-1 
  Version table: *** 
    2020.1-1 500 500 gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages 
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

and `which gmx` gives: `/usr/bin/gmx`

Comment: How did you installed both versions of Gromacs? What is your Ubuntu version? What is the output of `apt-cache policy gromacs` and `which gmx` ?

Comment: Thanks Norbert - My Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 20.04. I downloaded Gromacs 2019.4 from the Gromacs site - I didn't download version 2020.1. The output of "apt-cache policy gromacs" is:gromacs:
  Installed: 2020.1-1
  Candidate: 2020.1-1
  Version table:
 *** 2020.1-1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status    and "which gmx" gives; 
/usr/bin/gmx

Answer (score 0):

To access older locally installed version of Gromacs you have to remove deb-packaged version by

```
sudo apt-get autopurge gromacs
```

and then try to find the executables of 2019.4. Maybe add it to $PATH variable or create a symlink to it in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: OK thanks N0rbert - I'll have a think about that and try it out. I can imagine getting in a mess with this but I can always re-download and install version 2019.4 (though would be nice to be confident that the same automatic upgrade won't happen again!)

Comment: Gromacs is in the Universe (not Main) pocket, and had no security patches. Therefore it would not have been picked up by Unattended Upgrades using it's default settings. Perhaps a human changed those settings. Or a human ran the update, and ignored that gromacs was on the list of packages to be upgraded. Or perhaps the package has been there longer than you think.

Comment: thanks user535733, On reflection I suspect that you are right and that I (I'm the only "human" using the workstation at the mo!) didn't notice that gromacs was on the list of packages to be upgraded. I've only just changed OS from Centos to Ubuntu a couple of months ago and not completely familiar with it... Prbly easier for me to reinstall the version i need and be careful with upgrades in future